# How To extract value from Array Reference in Perl

Tags: perl

I have an array reference $data from which I have extract the values.Currently, when I do a Dumper on $data it is as below:

```
print Dumper @$data;
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = ' ANC';

$VAR2 = 'BET';
```

How can I access the elements in $Var2?

Comment: I got it.. it's by $data->[1]

Comment: If you have found your own solution then please write an answer and accept it. That way other users of the site will see that the problem has been resolved, and people who have a similar issue can come here to find an answer

Comment: @Miller: The OP's solution belongs as an *answer*, not as an update to his question :)

Comment: @Borodin I was just trying to make sure that people saw that he found an answer and didn't waste time.  I agree that the ideal intended place is the answer section though

Comment: @Miller: In retrospect I agree. I didn't expect him to just run away with his answer without giving anything back, but hey

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can use `$$data[1]`, since `$data` is a reference to an array, you can use it just like an ordinary array, `$data` is the name, so you can use `@$data` represent the whole array, and `$$data[n]` to access element in array.

There is more than one way to do it!

Comment: I realize you don't have the privilege of commenting on other people's questions yet, but a comment is the best place if you have to make a joke.

Comment: @sloger: Your answer is valid, but you should explain yourself as well as writing bare code. I tried to edit your answer to remove the graphic but that left it too short. If you can write something useful to explain *why* your answer is a good one then please do so, otherwise I will vote for it to be deleted

Comment: @sloger: Please stop using character art in your posts